# Ubuntu Run Dialogue with arguments

Tags: command-line

I added the following script to my .bashrc:

```
jira () {
    google-chrome https://xxx.atlassian.net/browse/ISSUE-$1
}
```

Note the `$1` at the end.

In my terminal, running `jira 1458` works perfectly, but when using the Run Dialogue (<kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>F2</kbd>), I get a `command not found error`.

[image: screenshot]).

Any idea why the behavior is different and how I can pass an argument to my jira command?

Comment: Your DE does not rely on your `bashrc` as it is not a bash shell. Add e.g. `/home/joren/bin` to your path, put the script there and make sure that it (the dir) is sourced by `.profile` then you can run commands from DE's `run`.

Comment: @Fixman, thanks! That works. A small sidenote though: just executing `jira` did work with my `bashrc` experiment.

Comment: I assume that your `.profile` already sorurces `.bashrc`?

Comment: That's correct. I didn't tweak this, so I guess this is standard on Ubuntu 18.04.